# Overwrite eclipse shortcuts for custom use

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a Eclipse based GUI(written in Java) for my product and for a particular operation I want to use Ctrl+Shift+R key combination as the shortcut. Now since Eclipse already uses this shortcut I'm not able to assign a custom operation to that key combination.

Is there a way to overwrite shortcut keys which Eclipse already uses for ones' custom use?

Comment: Is this an RCP you are asking about? You can define a new 'context' in an RCP with different key bindings which are active when the context is activated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a new scheme for your shortcuts in **plugin.xml** and set your scheme as the default using the **plugin_customization.ini**.

Add below mentioned line in **plugin_customization.ini**:
org.eclipse.ui/KEY_CONFIGURATION_ID = <your scheme id>

Try following changes in your **plugin.xml**:

Replace value in schemeId from org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration with your schemeId.

 
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
        <key sequence="Ctrl+Shift+R"
            commandId="your.command.id"
            schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"  **<!--Change here-->** 
            contextId="your.context.id"/>
    </extension>

**Note:** You need to replace schemeId in every <key> tag. If not changed, other shortcuts of your application (if any) will not work as it wont get the ui binding from eclipse anymore.

For more details refer:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommandsKeybindings/article.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't "overwrite" the existing shortcut key. Instead, just change the existing mapping of **Ctrl+Shift+R** (Open Resource) to use another binding, and then **Ctrl+Shift+R** is available for you to assign.

To do this:

- Select **Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys**
- In the **type filter text** field enter **Open Resource** to display its details.
- Position the cursor in the **Binding** field and then press the keys you wish to use for opening the **Open Resource** window.
- The keys you pressed will be automatically populated in the **Binding** field. In the screen shot below I chose **Ctrl+Shift+Z**.
- Click **Apply and Close** and verify that **Ctrl+Shift+Z** now opens the **Open Resource** window.
- Also, type **Ctrl+Shift+R** to verify that nothing happens. That binding is now available for your custom assignment.

[image: binding]

Answer (score 0):

The main preference page can be found under `Window > Preferences > General > Keys` and you can overwrite the shortcut.